# how to add third party jar in tomcat6 lib (C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\lib) directory

Tags: tomcat6

Can someone help me how to add third party jar in tomcat6 lib directory.

I tried to past project required jar files into tomcat6 lib directory (C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\lib). The jar file was copied successfully but it is not visible. When I try to past again it is saying the jar file is already available in current folder. I am using the windows 8 operating system.

Regards,
Ramesh.